# Can new be called on anything other than a class/function

Tags: javascript, constructor

Is it possible to directly modify objects so that they can be created with the `new` keyword, or does that only apply to functions/classes? As an example:

```
const bird = {
    swim() {return 'Swim';},
    fly() {return 'Fly';}
};
let b1 = Object.create(bird);

bird.constructor = function(){console.log('via constructor')};
let b2 = new bird();
```

There's no practical use of this, I'm more just learning things and seeing how `new` works and such.

Comment: `()` can only be used with functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Using `new` results in [`EvaluateNew`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-evaluatenew) being called, which does

> 5. If IsConstructor(constructor) is false, throw a TypeError exception.

which [does](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-isconstructor)

> 2. If argument has a [[Construct]] internal method, return true.

and that internal property is [only permitted on functions](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-essential-internal-methods):

> A constructor is an object that supports the [[Construct]] internal method. Every object that supports `[[Construct]]` must support `[[Call]]`; that is, every constructor must be a function object.